# Scrape data from paginated contents

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

I have a website which make use of AJAX scroll pagination (on scroll it loads more contents). By default its showing 25 items and am able to scrape those.

How do I scrape data from paginated contents?

I am scraping the data using BeautifulSoup and by using a cronjob.

My code:

```
r=requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
content=soup.find_all('section',{'class':'jrcl'})
for c in content:
    try:
        links=c.select('a')[1]['href']
        web_link=requests.get(links)
        print "web",links
    except:
        links=c.select('a')[0]['href']
        web_link=requests.get(links)
        print "web",links
    content_data=web_link.text
    soup_content = BeautifulSoup(content_data)
    text=soup_content.find('section',{'class':'jdlc'})
    vendor=VendorDetails()
    vendor.company=text.select('.fn')[0].text
    vendor.source=links
    vendor.address=text.select('.jadlt')[0].text
    try:
        contact=text.select('.tel')[0]['href']
        vendor.contact=contact.replace('tel:',' ')
        contact2=text.select('.tel')[0]['href']
        vendor.contact2=contact2.replace('tel:',' ')
    except:
        contact=text.select('.tel')[0]['href']
        vendor.contact=contact.replace('tel:',' ')
    vendor.save()
```

Comment: Look in your browser development console; each time you scroll an AJAX request is made. Make that same AJAX request in your Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used selenium and phantom js to do this.I used window.scrollTo to get the entire page and this worked for me

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):

       driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

       driver.get("http://example.com")
       time.sleep(3)

        # elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
        driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)

        no_of_pagedowns = 20

        while no_of_pagedowns:
            # elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(1)
            no_of_pagedowns-=1

        post_elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jcn")
        driver.save_screenshot('testing.png')
        for post in post_elems:
            ###Operations to be done
    driver.close()
```